# Pyomo optimisation not working (gas plant dispatch)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, solver, pyomo, energy

**background**

I am trying to write an pyomo script to optimally dispatch a gas plant based on perfect foresight of electricity prices. I believe I am 90% of the way there, just a few issues.

**Problem**

The script runs, but the solver is never dispatching the plant, even where it should be, in the example provided below, its returning zero, yet if I was to manually calculate it, I can earn at least $8131 of potential profit. I suspect the problem is with how I have either defined my variables, or with how I've written the constraints.

1. Gas Plant takes 10 minutes to boot up from a cold start
2. Gas Plant can only consume 9000 GJ of gas in a single day

**Help Requested**

Could someone please have a look at my code and see what I am missing in the constraint equations?

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.core import *


# ---------------------
# Main Functions
# ---------------------
def model_to_df(model, first_period, last_period):

    # Need to increase the first & last period by 1 because of pyomo indexing
    # and add 1 to the value of last model period because of the range
    periods = range(model.T[first_period + 1], model.T[last_period + 1] + 1)
    rrp = [model.P.extract_values()[None][i] for i in periods]
    GasOn = [value(model.GasOn[i]) for i in periods]
    GasUnit_mw = [value(model.GasUnit_mw[i]) for i in periods]
    GasUse = [value(model.GasUse[i]) for i in periods]

    df_dict = dict(
        period=periods,
        rrp=rrp,
        GasOn=GasOn,
        GasUnit_mw=GasUnit_mw,
        GasUse=GasUse
    )

    df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

    return df


def optimize_year(df, gunits, gnet, gprice, vom, cold_gas_p_unit, hr, max_gas, sys_use,
                  first_model_period, last_model_period):

    """
    Optimize behavior of a gas plant over a time period
    Assume perfect foresight of electricity prices.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : dataframe
        dataframe with columns of hourly LBMP and the hour of the year
    gunits : int
        number of gas turbines
    gnet : double
        size in MW's of each gas turbine
    gprice : double
        the price of gas $/GJ
    vom  : double
        the variable cost of gas $/MWh dispatched
    cold_gas_p_unit  : double
        the amount of gas in GJ used in 5 minutes while booting up from cold start
    hr  : double
        heat rate, the amount of gas consumed per MWh produced (GJ/MWh)
    sys_use  : double
        auxillary gas usage, percentage
    max_gas  : double
        the maximum amount of gas (GJ) available to use in a period
    first_model_period : int, optional
        Set the first period of the year to be considered in the optimization
    last_model_period : int, optional
        Set the last period of the year to be considered in the optimization

    Returns
    -------
    dataframe
        Gas plant operational stats and time stamp
    """

    # Filter the data
    df = df.loc[first_model_period:last_model_period, :]

    model = ConcreteModel()

    # Define model parameters
    model.T = Set(initialize=df.period.tolist(), doc='periods of year', ordered=True)
    model.P = Param(initialize=df.rrp.tolist(), doc='price for each period', within=Any)

    model.MaxGas = Param(initialize=max_gas, doc='Max gas usage (GJ) in 24 hour period', within=Any)

    model.GasOn = Var(model.T, bounds=(0, 1), initialize=0)
    model.GasUnit_mw = Var(model.T, bounds=(0, (gnet * gunits) / 12), initialize=0)
    model.GasUse = Var(model.T, bounds=(0, gunits*gnet / 12 * hr * (1+sys_use)), initialize=0)

    # *********************
    # GAS CONSTRAINTS
    # *********************
    def gas_on(model, t):
        'is gas plant on or off?'
        'gas plant needs 10 minutes (2 intervals) to boot up from a cold start'
        'during this period, it cannot output mws (energy)'
        if t <= 2:
            return model.GasUnit_mw[t] == 0
        elif value(model.GasOn[t-2] + model.GasOn[t-1] + model.GasOn[t]) <= 2:
            return model.GasUnit_mw[t] == 0
        else:
            return model.GasUnit_mw[t] >= 0

    model.gas_on_check = Constraint(model.T, rule=gas_on)

    def gas_volume_used(model, t):
        'how much gas is being used?'
        'during cold start, a small amount of gas is used'
        'during operation, gas is consumed based on the Heat Rate'
        if model.GasOn[t] == 1 and model.GasUnit_mw[t] == 0:
            return model.GasUse[t] == cold_gas_p_unit * gunits * (1+sys_use)
        else:
            return model.GasUse[t] == model.GasUnit_mw[t] * hr * (1+sys_use)

    model.gas_vol = Constraint(model.T, rule=gas_volume_used)

    def daily_max_gas(model, t):
        "only 9000 GJ of gas can be used in a single day"
        min_t = model.T.first()
        max_t = model.T.last()

        # Check all t until the last 24 hours
        if t <= max_t:
            return sum(model.GasUse[i] for i in range(min_t, max_t+1)) <= model.MaxGas
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip

    model.max_gas_vol = Constraint(model.T, rule=daily_max_gas)

    # Define the income, expenses, and profit
    gas_income = sum(df.loc[t, 'rrp'] * model.GasUnit_mw[t] for t in model.T)
    gas_expenses = sum(model.GasUse[t] * gprice + model.GasUnit_mw[t] * vom for t in model.T)
    profit = gas_income - gas_expenses
    model.objective = Objective(expr=profit, sense=maximize)

    # Solve the model
    solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
    solver.solve(model)

    results_df = model_to_df(model, first_period=first_model_period, last_period=last_model_period)
    results_df['local_time'] = df.loc[:, 'local_time']

    return results_df


# *********************
# RUN SCRIPT
# *********************
# Import file
df = pd.read_csv('raw_prices.csv')

# New Index
df['period'] = df.reset_index().index

# get current Year
first_model_period = 0
last_model_period = df['period'].iloc[-1]

# Gas Inputs
gunits = 3 # No units
gnet = 58.5 # MW/unit
srmc = 115.49 # $/MWh
vom = 6.18 # $/MWh
gprice = 10.206 # $/GJ
cold_gas_p_unit = 15.75 # GJ/unit/5mins
hr = 10.5 # GJ/MWh
sys_use = 0.02 # %
max_gas = 9000 # GJ

# Run Model
results_df = optimize_year(df=df, gunits=gunits, gnet=gnet, gprice=gprice, vom=vom, cold_gas_p_unit=cold_gas_p_unit,
                           hr=hr, max_gas=max_gas, sys_use=sys_use,
                           first_model_period=first_model_period, last_model_period=last_model_period)

# ---------------------
# Write the file out and remove the index
# ---------------------
print('ran successfully')
results_df.to_csv('optimised_output.csv', index=False)
```

**Example Data**

```
local_time      rrp
3/07/2022 16:40 64.99
3/07/2022 16:45 73.10744
3/07/2022 16:50 74.21746
3/07/2022 16:55 95.90964
3/07/2022 17:00 89.60728
3/07/2022 17:05 90.37018
3/07/2022 17:10 92.52947
3/07/2022 17:15 100.1449
3/07/2022 17:20 103.70199
3/07/2022 17:25 290.2848
3/07/2022 17:30 115.40232
3/07/2022 17:35 121.00009
3/07/2022 17:40 294.62543
3/07/2022 17:45 121
3/07/2022 17:50 294.69446
3/07/2022 17:55 124.90664
3/07/2022 18:00 117.21929
3/07/2022 18:05 115.60193
3/07/2022 18:10 121
3/07/2022 18:15 148.20186
3/07/2022 18:20 123.11763
3/07/2022 18:25 120.99996
3/07/2022 18:30 121
3/07/2022 18:35 121
3/07/2022 18:40 121
3/07/2022 18:45 120.77726
3/07/2022 18:50 105.44435
3/07/2022 18:55 104.22928
3/07/2022 19:00 102.26646
3/07/2022 19:05 99.5896
3/07/2022 19:10 95.5881
3/07/2022 19:15 88
3/07/2022 19:20 88
3/07/2022 19:25 88
3/07/2022 19:30 96.97537
3/07/2022 19:35 88
3/07/2022 19:40 86.39322
3/07/2022 19:45 88
3/07/2022 19:50 85.97703
3/07/2022 19:55 86
3/07/2022 20:00 87.61047
3/07/2022 20:05 88
3/07/2022 20:10 88
3/07/2022 20:15 85.34908
3/07/2022 20:20 85.1
3/07/2022 20:25 71.01181
3/07/2022 20:30 84.88422
3/07/2022 20:35 85.39669
3/07/2022 20:40 86.02542
3/07/2022 20:45 84.87425
3/07/2022 20:50 70.0652
3/07/2022 20:55 70.65106
3/07/2022 21:00 70.53063
3/07/2022 21:05 68.27
3/07/2022 21:10 68.86159
3/07/2022 21:15 68.32018
3/07/2022 21:20 67.30473
3/07/2022 21:25 66.78292
3/07/2022 21:30 66.02195
3/07/2022 21:35 66.40755
```